# Separate data from a text cum data file in matlab

Tags: matlab

My file contains text in first few lines and the data afterward. It looks like this -

#

SCALARS ESA FLOAT

LOOKUP_TABLE default

1.135409e-02

5.018007e-03

1.693268e-02

1.585292e-02

1.872202e-03

6.062706e-03

2.285194e-02

1.173866e-02

#

From this, how do i just obtain the data and store it to a variable in matlab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textscan` function will be quite useful here, and you can find a thorough introduction here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

Most of the MATLAB text import functions (including `textscan`) allow you to specify how many lines of text at the start of the file should be ignored, e.g.: `'HeaderLines',2` would be appropriate for your file.

An alternative method (such as if the header contains useful information is to read and store the header text:

```
fileID = fopen('testFile.txt');   % open connection to file
header = textscan(fileID,'%s',2,'delimiter','\n');   % read 2 header lines as strings
data = textscan(fileID,'%f','delimiter','\n');   % read till end of file as floats
fclose(fileID);   % close connection to file
```